# How launch an express Web Node.js from a batch file

Tags: node.js, express, batch-file

I have an app.js script that contains an express node website

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static('public'));
…
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('avalaible at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

until now I launch website by writing in cmd

> node ./app.js

Then I go to adress http://localhost:3000 in my browser

I would have a batch or another way to those operations just by doucle click on a file

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Node js project folder create a .bat file and put this on it:

```
 node ./app.js
 start "" http://localhost:3000
```

when you click the file this should launch your nodejs app and open your default browser on the given address.